# Limit searches per minute in my mysql database

Tags: php, security, pdo

I have a website offering a public database which can be searched by a simple form. I am using PDO for the queries.
I tried to Google, but I feel like I am missing the right keyword to help myself.

I would like to limit the searches every user can make to 5 searches per minute. What would be the right way of doing this with low effort? I don't need a high security solution, something to slow everything down a bit would help.

Is there a name for this? What can I search for?

```
// Create a session variable called something like this after you start the session:
$_SESSION['user_start'] = time();

// Then when they get to submitting the payment, just check whether they're within the 5 minute window
if (time() - $_SESSION['user_start'] < 300) { // 300 seconds = 5 minutes
    // they're within the 5 minutes so save the details to the database
} else {
    // sorry, you're out of time
   unset($_SESSION['user_start']); // and unset any other session vars for this task
}
```

Comment: You can set a cookie whenever a user searches for data(it stores the first time the user searched and 1 as the number of searches) then increment it for every subsequent search, blocking the search if it's value reaches the maximum and the time of the first search being less than 5 minutes ago. 
The solution is not fool-proof but is quick and easy and works for most use cases.

Comment: Thanks to you too! Found the solution using session which I already had included. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't limit it from MySQL's settings. But you can avoid it with PHP. What you should do is set a SESSION per every user and set a parameter named "SearchTimes". Add 1 to it for every search if it's 5 stop the search operation. You can add some more Security to it with IP Address blocking.

Comment: Actually my users are required to log in with their Steam account, which would make this solution pretty safe. So I already have sessions for my users and I can check for session IDs and all this stuff. The question is, where can I store the amount of searches? And how can I block it then? (I am new to all this and only managed to make the login and session work with the help of a friend). Oh, and how can I remove the limitation after a certain amount of time?

Comment: I found this: http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/sessions.shtml - is "Storing and Accessing Variables" the thing I am looking for? Everything seems clear to me, except how I can clean a variable once a minute.

Comment: You can write it to current Session. What you are going to do is you gonna put this parameter to Session : 

$_SESSION['SearchAmount'] = 0;

before every search you will check this : 

if( $_SESSION['SearchAmount'] < 5) {
 // do your search stuff
 $_SESSION['SearchAmount'] += 1;
}else{
  // user can't search.
}

Comment: Ah, I totally understand! Thanks for the explanation! I added something to my original post. Will this work to timeout the limitation after 60 seconds?

Comment: No it won't work with timeout. If you want timeout you can do something like this : 

if( $_SESSION['LastSearchTime'] <= time() - 60 ){
$_SESSION['SearchAmount'] = 0;
}
if( $_SESSION['SearchAmount'] < 5) { 
/* do your search staff */ 
$_SESSION['LastSearchTime'] = time();
$_SESSION['SearchAmount'] += 1; 
}else{ 
// user can't search. 
}

Comment: Okay, I understand that code! Thanks a lot, Erol KESKIN! You were a big help to me!

Comment: If you can give one up reputation to me i will glad too :) Just kidding, have a nice day sir.